# Page alignment with wide background image

Tags: html, css, formatting, stylesheet

http://www.thredup.com/boutiques

So I noticed when displaying my site on iPad (or any iOS device), the page is left aligned. I did a little digging to make sure `margin: 0 auto` was implemented correctly and all divs were centered appropriately. What I realized is that this issue is caused by the stylizing of the footer and is not iPad specific -- it actually happens on all all web browsers, it just manifests differently. The page content generally stays within 960px wide, however the footer (#footer => #footer_bg) is larger (1200px) to accommodate its background image.  When on Chrome/Safari on my Mac, the page appears to be displayed centered/correctly **until** the window is made smaller than about 1200px wide. When the window is smaller than this, there's a mysterious white space off to the right. Removing the #footer_bg width of 1200px fixes the issue, but then the footer background isn't aligned correctly with the footer content.

Anyone have advice on how to fix this? Ideally the background image wouldn't need to be redesigned and the footer background margins would gradually hide/appear depended upon the window width. The left edge of the footer content should stay aligned with the left edge of the rest of the page.

Comment: For future users or those who can't access the link, could you please post some of the website CSS into this question?

Comment: I know you're not asking for design options, but you've got a fixed width footer that doesn't scale. You should consider floating your 'dots' as a background and let them get sacrificed off the left hand side of the page and reserve the space just for your footer content...keeping it the same 960px as your primary content above. Or, when you hit the media query of <=1200px, get rid of that image entirely and set your footer width to match.

Answer (score 1):

Add `max-width: 100%;` to your `#footer_bg` style.

Then the footer width will decrease below 1200px if the page is smaller.

And you might need to change the `background-position` to something like `center`, to move the background correctly with it.